# Angular Mat Table Design Creation with a pattern row

Tags: javascript, html, css, design-patterns, html-table

How can I achieve this design which will work Dynamically whenever there is an increment of a row

[image]

Comment: Kindly share your code of attempt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.